# Slim Micro-framework / Twig Template language engine alternative to session variable

Tags: php, session, twig, slim, php-5.3

I am using Slim Microframework and Twig template language, just to be more precise:

```
"slim/slim": "^3.0",
"slim/twig-view": "^2.0",
"slim/php-view": "^2.0",
```

My issue has to do with storing session variables within the twig system.

The home page is a login page where when the user submit the form, the action of the form takes it to the a function page that validates the user credentials and if the credentials is false, than the following session variable is created

```
   $_SESSION['error_login_message'] = "Sorry, your credentials are invalid";
```

he is then redirected to the login page and my attempt was to display the session variable there, but that doesn't seem to work with twig (the login page runs under the twig template). I have also tried `{{ session.error_login_message }}` but that hasn't help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the twig template does not have access to the session. Either add the data when you render the template, or globally append it to all templates.

In route:

```
$this->view->render($response, "template.twig", [
    "session" => $_SESSION
]);
```

Globally:

```
$app->getContainer()["view"]["session"] = $_SESSION;
```